# I can't access my external HDD on ChromeOS Flex

Tags: chrome-os

`lsblk` isn't listing my HDD.

```
NAME  MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
vda   254:0    0 62.6M  1 disk /opt/google/cros-containers
vdb   254:16   0   10G  0 disk /dev/net/tun
pmem0 259:0    0  704M  0 disk 
prafulbadiger6342@penguin:~$
```

I can't format it using the 'Format Device' option in the Files app as it has become unclickable.

Attached image for reference.[image]

Comment: Are you sure the drive is fine? Have you tested it somewhere else?